# Submitting a form with radio button to store them in firebase questionnaire

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I wanted to store +1 on firebase array by using radiobuttons. How can i manipulate the array with the firebase to store yes and no which is 0 and 1.

This is what I've done. when i submitted it and when radioyes is checked. results array which is my collections with the array of 0 and 1 and if Yes 0 + =1

```
methods: 
{
    submitAnswers() 
    {
       if (radioYes === checked)
       {
           results.array[0] += 1
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your *data* ? I am not sold on the way you are handling the results, though

Comment: i'd just changed my db earlier. and added a collection to a collection.

Comment: -> users - user.id ->q1-yes-no

Answer (score 0):

```
 db
        .collection("professors").doc('professors.id').collection('q1')
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            const data = {
              id: doc.id,
              name: doc.data().name,
              Q1: doc.data().Q1
            };
                        this.professors.push(data);
                        console.log(doc.data())
          });
        });

here..
```